# SQL Server exec keyword

Tags: sql-server, exec

What is the role of exec keyword in T-SQL?

I tried

```
EXEC sp_rename 'mytable.foo', 'bar', 'column';
/* and */
sp_rename 'mytable.foo', 'bar', 'column';
```

Both commands produced seemingly same result.

Comment: Also, what is the role of GO keyword? It doesn't seem to play any role either.

Comment: The documentation explains clearly what EXEC is for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

Comment: And GO is NOT a keyword. It is the default batch separator in SSMS.

Comment: @Sam GO is used to define a batch. for example, variables are only accessible in the same batch that they have been defined. so using GO in a wrong line can close the batch, thus the variables defined inside it will not be accessible any more out side of the batch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EXEC keyword tells SQL that you want to run a stored procedure, function or character string. 
Syntax can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

EXEC is essential for using transact SQL, when you want to built a SQL statement dynamically. Common practice for this is to build a sql statement in a temporary variable string, then use the EXECUTE keyword to execute it.

i.e.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)

DECLARE @DynamicColumnName varchar(20)

DECLARE @SomeDatabase varchar(20)

SELECT @DynamicColumnName =  'Column1'

SELECT @SomeDatabase = 'MyDB'

SELECT @SQL = 'USE ' +@SomeDatabase +
' INSERT INTO #NewTable
  SELECT '+@DyanmicColumnName + 
  ' FROM Mytable'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

The above would execute the following statement:
'USE MyDB 
INSERT INTO #NewTable SELECT Column1 FROM Mytable'

As for GO, it is a command to end a batch of statements. This can be used for a variety of reasons, but I would start your research here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Answer (score 11):

If the `EXEC XXX` is the first statement in your batch, then using `EXEC` is optional and you can simply call `XXX` without using `EXEC`. But if `EXEC` is not the first statement in your batch, you SHOULD specify the `EXEC` in order to call the `XXX`. However best practice is to use it in any situation as it can increase the readability of your code.